# A finite group of even order with no normal subgroup of index 2.

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group of even order and suppose that there exist an element $x\in Z(G)$ of order $2$, i.e $x$ is in the center of $G$ and satisfying $x^2=1$, $x\neq1$.

Is it possible that $G$ does not contains a normal subgroup of index $2$? I guess the answer is yes but I fail to find any examples of such groups.

Comment: If it has an element of order $2$ it already has even order

Comment: You right @Jorge.

Comment: I'm just curious why, if you have condition A which implies condition B, you decide to put condition B in the title instead of A

Comment: f you expect people to put in the effort to answer a question, then it is polite to put in some effort yourself. Just saying "I guess the answer" doesn't count as "effort" - you should at least explain *why* you think this. (But I feel I shouldn't have to point this out, considering you have been here for almost 8 years and have 4k rep. points.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the [binary tetrahedral group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tetrahedral_group) $2T\cong Q_8\rtimes C_3$.  It clearly has a central element of order $2$.  And it doesn't have an index-2 subgroup (as it must take the form $C_4\rtimes C_3\subset Q_8\rtimes C_3$ but none of the $C_4$ in $Q_8$ is actually normalised by $C_3$).

Comment: Thanks User10354138!

Answer (score -2):

The alternating groups, $\frak{A}_n$ do not have an index $2$ subgroup for $n\ge 4$.  The alternating group on $4$ letters is the smallest example, with only $12$ elements.

Comment: We also require that $G$ have a center of even order

Comment: That's the problem when the title is a question and the text is a different question.

Comment: This particular case is pretty bad because the condition that is ommited in the title is succint and implies the one that is actually on the title

Comment: Thanks @C Monsour !

Comment: Titles aren't _meant_ to be full problem statements. They are meant to be summaries. There is often no room for all the details of a problem in the title. Supplying more specifics in the question body is entirely fine. I see no reason to take issue with titles like this one, unless the title and the question body explicitly _contradict_ one another. Yes, this time it could've been included, but I don't think we should _expect_ it to. A brief title is also a fine goal.

Comment: @Arthur in this case both were possible though. But in any case who cares. I'm glad the question got a nice solution in the end.